# Pair the same data where some of them are missing in three ordered lists

Tags: c#, .net

The datasets are like below:

```
int[] X = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
int[] Y = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int[] Z = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 7 };
```

I am writing a C# program to pair the same value together and leave the missed value as null, the original dataset is in ascending order and the result should be sorted as well.

```
int[] a = { 0, 0, 0 };
int max = Math.Max(Math.Max(X.Count(), Y.Count()), Z.Count());
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    var x = X[i - a[0]];
    var y = Y[i - a[1]];
    var z = Z[i - a[2]];
    if (x == y && y == z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: {x}, {y}, {z}");
    }
    else
    {
        var v = x < y ? x : y;
        var minvalue = v < z ? v : z;
        bool[] list = {minvalue==x, minvalue == y, minvalue == z};
        int count = list.Where(x=>x.Equals(true)).Count();
        if (count == 1) {
            if (minvalue == x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: {x}, null, null");
                a[1] = a[1] + 1; a[2] = a[2] + 1;
            }
            else if (minvalue == y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: null, {y}, null");
                a[0] = a[0] + 1; a[2] = a[2] + 1;
            }
            else if (minvalue == z) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: null, null, {z}");
                a[0] = a[0] + 1; a[1] = a[1] + 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (minvalue == x)
            {
                if (x == y)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: {x}, {y}, null");
                    a[2] = a[2] + 1;
                }
                else if (x == z)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: {x}, null, {z}");
                    a[1] = a[1] + 1;
                }
            }
            else if (minvalue == y)
            {
                if (y == z)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: null, {y}, {z}");
                    a[0] = a[0] + 1;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have wrote something like this but it seems to dummy. Is there a better way to Do it.

Also the line of "7" is not showing because none of the list is long enough to count all existing number.

The output is shown as below:

Upsert: 1, 1, 1

Upsert: 2, 2, 2

Upsert: 3, null, null

Upsert: null, 4, 4

Upsert: 5, 5, null

Upsert: 6, 6, 6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIGP4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to store all values in one instance and then check it.

```
public class Number
{
   public int? X { get; private set; }
   public int? Y { get; private set; }
   public int? Z { get; private set; }

   public Number(int? x, int? y, int? z)
   {
      X = x;
      Y = y;
      Z = Z;
   }
   
   public override ToString()
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: {X} {Y} {Z}");
   }
   
}
```

Now you can store and print expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with Linq https://dotnetfiddle.net/HF83qt

```
int[] X = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
int[] Y = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int[] Z = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 7 };

Func<int[], int, string> GetElement = (x, y) => x.Contains(y) ? y.ToString() :"null";
foreach(int e in X.Union(Y).Union(Z).OrderBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Upsert: {GetElement(X, e)}, {GetElement(Y, e)}, {GetElement(Z, e)}");
}
```